# Cannot update mongodb 2.4 on centos 6.6

Tags: centos, yum, virtualbox, mongodb

I am trying to update my mongodb 2.4 to 2.6 but I can't seem to download all the packages. I successfully downloaded all of it before except `mongodb-org`. I ran `yum clean all` to clear the cache that might cause the issue. After that, I can't download anything anymore except `mongodb-org-server` when I tried `yum update mongodb-org`

Here's a screenshot for your overview: http://prntscr.com/9aeusp

```
Error Downloading Packages:
  mongodb-org-shell-2.6.11-1.i686: failure: RPMS/mongodb-org-shell-2.6.11-1.i686.rpm from mongodb: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  mongodb-org-tools-2.6.11-1.i686: failure: RPMS/mongodb-org-tools-2.6.11-1.i686.rpm from mongodb: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  mongodb-org-2.6.11-1.i686: failure: RPMS/mongodb-org-2.6.11-1.i686.rpm from mongodb: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  mongodb-org-mongos-2.6.11-1.i686: failure: RPMS/mongodb-org-mongos-2.6.11-1.i686.rpm from mongodb: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

I tried accessing the url's in the browser and I successfully downloaded the rpm files. What do you guys think is causing the issue?

Here is my `/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo` in case you might ask.

```
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/i686/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

Update:

Today I successfully downloaded all the dependencies except for the last one (as seen in the screenshot). You will notice that only mongodb-org is not highlighted; Hinting that it is not yet downloaded.

http://prntscr.com/9aiwka

I am pretty sure that yum does not use any proxies as what @kubanczyk says. I haven't configured anything like that before (unless there is a proxy set by default after a fresh install).

Just to let you know. I am running `centos 6.6` on `Virtualbox 5.0.10 r104061` under Ubuntu. The network settings are Bridged Adapter (Intel PRO/100 MT Desktop 82540EM). The virtual machine has a static ip set with the following network script.

```
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=08:00:27:AC:A0:96
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=72a2164a-7344-47dc-ad75-89822dbf6002
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=192.168.1.109
NAME="Sys Eth0"
IPV6INIT=no
```

Comment: Check your Internet connection.

Comment: the vm im running can successfully ping and download files from the internet

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a proxy issue to me. The browser you use on the same box has a proxy configured differently than [yum's own proxy](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-yum-proxy-server.html). For example, maybe yum has some incorrect old proxy and browser works great with no proxy at all.